# Android : resolve external dependencies over Artifactory with Gradle

Tags: android, dependencies, gradle, libraries, artifactory

So we are currently working on the migration of ant building/publishing scripts for Android projects to the new Android Gradle build system.

Our projects generally relies on both internal and third-party libraries. The internal libraries have been published on Artifactory repositories and now I'm struggling to resolve the dependencies over them.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }

        maven{
            url 'http://dl.bintray.com/jfrog/jfrog-jars'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
        classpath(group: 'org.jfrog.buildinfo', name: 'build-info-extractor-gradle', version: '2.1.0')
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'artifactory'

artifactory {
    contextUrl = 'my_artifactory_url'

    resolve {
        repository {
            repoKey = 'libs-snapshot'
            maven = true
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile(group: 'groupId', name: 'artifact1Id', version: 'artifact1Version')
    compile(group: 'groupId', name: 'artifact2Id', version: 'artifact2Version')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

I basically used built-in options in Artifactory to generate the artifactory{} section and the two compile() lines. But I'm having this error when trying to build (and I keep having it whatever minor changes I tried) :

```
15:34:23.208 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
15:34:23.209 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] 
15:34:23.210 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
15:34:23.210 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] A problem occurred configuring project ':GradleArtifactoryTest'.
15:34:23.210 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
15:34:23.211 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':GradleArtifactoryTest:compile'.
15:34:23.211 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]       > Could not find groupId:artifact1Id:artifact1Version.
15:34:23.212 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]         Required by:
15:34:23.212 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]             workspace_gradle-artifactory-test:GradleArtifactoryTest:unspecified
15:34:23.213 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]       > Could not find groupId:artifact2Id:artifact2Version.
15:34:23.213 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]         Required by:
15:34:23.214 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]             workspace_gradle-artifactory-test:GradleArtifactoryTest:unspecified
```

I'm probably missing something big, but as a newcomer to Gradle, Maven & Artifactory, I feel kinda lost for the moment. Can someone enlighten me or perhaps tell me how can I get more precise informations on the problem (I tried the --debug and --info, --s and --S options and it was not very helpful). The initial exception is always :

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find groupId:artifact1Id:artifact1Version.
Required by:
14:20:51.833 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]     workspace_gradle-artifactory-test:GradleArtifactoryTest:unspecified
14:20:51.833 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.LazyDependencyToModuleResolver$StaticVersionResolveResult.notFound(LazyDependencyToModuleResolver.java:148)
14:20:51.834 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.LazyDependencyToModuleResolver$AbstractVersionResolveResult.resolve(LazyDependencyToModuleResolver.java:89)
14:20:51.834 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder$ModuleVersionSelectorResolveState.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:943)
14:20:51.835 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder$DefaultModuleRevisionResolveState.getMetaData(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:648)
14:20:51.835 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.calculateTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:333)
14:20:51.836 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.attachToTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:309)
14:20:51.836 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder.traverseGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:130)
14:20:51.836 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:66)
14:20:51.837 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:7
```

The 'gradle refresh-dependencies --info' command didn't give more useful information. What is very troubling though is that the debug traces never mentionned the contextUrl I provided. Instead I got the following (which, I suppose, is not what I should have) :

```
selecting new module version groupId#artifact1Id;artifact1Version
16:58:08.827 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.UserResolverChain] Attempting to resolve module 'groupId:artifact1Id:artifact1Version' using repositories [maven, maven2]
16:58:08.829 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver] Loading /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/groupId/artifact1Id/artifact1version/artifact1Id-artifact1Version.pom
16:58:08.832 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver] Resource not reachable for groupId#artifact1Id;artifact1Version: res=MissingResource: /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/groupId/artifact1Id/artifact1version/artifact1Id-artifact1Version.pom
16:58:08.833 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver] Loading /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/groupId/artifact1Id/artifact1version/artifact1Id-artifact1Version.apklib
16:58:08.840 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver] Resource not reachable for groupId#artifact1Id;artifact1Version: res=MissingResource: /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/groupId/artifact1Id/artifact1version/artifact1Id-artifact1Version.apklib
```

Comment: Note that you've declared no repositories to resolve dependencies from. The repositories declared in the 'buildscript' section apply only to the project evaluation phase (for pulling plugins, applying scripts, etc.); they don't apply to the build phase itself

Comment: Well, isn't the artifactory{} section actually declaring the repository to use? Perhaps I'm confused...

Comment: Yes, but the artifact you're searching for is probably not reachable via your libs-snapshots repository

Comment: According to what I can see in Artifactory, I can't find a reason why it could not be reachable. Problem is, the error message is just not helpful at all. Indeed, whatever I do (put a wrong contextUrl to Artifactory, force authentication with wrong credentials or put an inexistant version for the artifact, etc.) I always get THAT same message. Isn't there any way to have a more precise idea of what is going wrong?

Comment: You can run 'gradle refresh-dependencies --info' to see the exact requests made by Gradle's resolvers

Comment: @noamt : ok, I just understood what you meant in your first comment. It was indeed missing the repositories {} section that actually allows the connection with Artifactory. I am still a bit confused why this is not directly handled by the artifactory {} section but at least it is working now.

Comment: can you please post your full working build.gradle file? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @noamt said the only thing wrong was the fact I was not declaring a repositories {} section that actually allows the connection with Artifactory. I am still a bit confused why this is not directly handled by the artifactory {} section but at least it is working now.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how u solved your issue. I didnt really get it :/

Comment: Well, it's actually not entirely resolved. As I didn't manage to get the artifactory{} section working, I just replaced the whole stuff with simple declaration of maven repositories `repositories {
    maven {

        url "http://192.168.2.130:8081/artifactory/simple/libs-release" }}
`.

Answer (score 0):

you have double checked that "groupId:artifact2Id:artifact2Version" is in your artifactory repository? or do you accidently rely on a variable here instead of the string?

cheers,
René

Comment: Yes, I definitely checked that (many many times actually). I'm pretty sure the problem is somewhere else. Note that I got the exact same error message when I change the artifactory contextUrl for a wrong url so at that point I'm not even sure that the artifactory is reached.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that gradle by default picks up the android `sdk` repository:

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USER\android-sdks\extras\android\m2repository
```

Instead of:

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USER\.m2\repository
```

When looking for artifacts but the later when downloading them. Do a comparison and check if they are being downloaded in the second one.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you but there is actually no download (in any directory). It clearly search for artifacts locally (in Android Studio SDK to be precise), yet they haven't been downloaded. This is what baffle me.