# In Gradle, what is the artifactory.resolve closure for?

Tags: gradle, artifactory

It adds the listed repository *after* all the projects have been evaluated (i.e. after their dependencies have been already found), so where is it actually used? Is there another set of resolution that happens on publishing?

(related questions: [Gradle artifactory plugin cannot resolve dependency on configuration phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27692607/gradle-artifactory-plugin-cannot-resolve-dependency-on-configuration-phase) ; [Android : resolve external dependencies over Artifactory with Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985942/android-resolve-external-dependencies-over-artifactory-with-gradle) )

Comment: The fact that project is evaluated does not necessarily mean that it has already resolved it's dependencies.

Comment: Can you expand on that? It seems to, specifically for dependencies listed in the toplevel `dependencies` closure...